# RecyclerView in NestedScrollView with horizontal-scolling

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, nestedscrollview

I want to result like this:

[image]

which can do **horizontal-scrolling**.

But in fact, like this below:

[image]

Which can't display all item and not horizontal-layout.

who can help me ? thanks. other way can reach my wanted result here?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images , then edit or make a new question with images properly placed into it. Make sure to check at preview if everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Layout manager to RecylerView.

```
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recylcerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

This will make the RecylerView horizontal.

Comment: I set the LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL but  RecyclerView in NestedScrollView display vertical，not horizontal

Answer (score 0):

**To set recyclerView as horizontal scrollView you can use LinearLayoutManager. by default it sets vertical scroll behaviour.**

```
LinearLayoutManager layout = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);//0 Horizontal , 1 vertical
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layout);
```

**in layout.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/yourRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/layout_past_round_header"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:overScrollMode="never" />
```

**in your NestedScrollView add this**

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```